# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined beqause it is unexistant

Tags: javascript, html, json

what is the best way to say devenitions=true? i cant figgure it out...

```
if (!defenitieGetoond) {
  getDef();
  defenitieGetoond = true;
} else {
  getWoord();
  defenitieGetoond = false;
}
```

This is my loop who expects that there is always a defenition? but in my json file this is not always the case. it searches to the Json file as follows.

```
function getDef() {
  document.getElementById("demo_").innerHTML = "<br>" + savedWord[1].definitions[0].definition
  //         +  "<br>" + "</br>"+ savedWord[1].definitions[1].definition
  ;
}
```

it needs to skip of ignore the Deffenitions[0] som how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should need to add check in case of element exist or not. like this -

```
function getDef(){
     const ele = document.getElementById("demo_");
     if (savedWord[1].definitions && savedWord[1].definitions.length) {
        ele.innerHTML = "<br>" + savedWord[1].definitions[0].definition 
//       +  "<br>" + "</br>"+ savedWord[1].definitions[1].definition;
     }
}
```